# Why isnt my javascript function working on key press?

Tags: javascript, function

Okay so my function isnt working when i try to do this

```js
function esp() {
    (function() {
      let initialize = function(data) {
          let regex = /if\(!\w+\['(\w+)']\)continue/;
          let result = regex.exec(data);
          if (result) {
              const inView = result[1];
              const push = Array.prototype.push;
              Array.prototype.push = function(...args) {
                  push.apply(this, args);
                  if (args[0] instanceof Object && args[0].isPlayer) {
                      Object.defineProperty(args[0], inView, {value: true, configurable: false});
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      const decode = window.TextDecoder.prototype.decode;
      window.TextDecoder.prototype.decode = function(...args) {
          let data = decode.apply(this, args);
          if (data.length > 1050000) { //1050000 ideal val
              console.log(data);
              initialize(data);
          }
          return data;
      }
  })();
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (document.activeElement !== document.body) return;
    var char = event.key.toUpperCase();
    switch (char) {
            case 'Q':
            esp();
            break;
    }
}, 750);
```

But it only doesnt work when i try to go to the function when Q is down but if i put esp(); right after the function it works. It also works when i do this but i need it to work on key down

```js
  (function() {
    let initialize = function(data) {
        let regex = /if\(!\w+\['(\w+)']\)continue/;
        let result = regex.exec(data);
        if (result) {
            const inView = result[1];
            const push = Array.prototype.push;
            Array.prototype.push = function(...args) {
                push.apply(this, args);
                if (args[0] instanceof Object && args[0].isPlayer) {
                    Object.defineProperty(args[0], inView, {value: true, configurable: false});
                }
            }
        }
    }

    const decode = window.TextDecoder.prototype.decode;
    window.TextDecoder.prototype.decode = function(...args) {
        let data = decode.apply(this, args);
        if (data.length > 1050000) { //1050000 ideal val
            console.log(data);
            initialize(data);
        }
        return data;
    }
})();
```

And this is the function inside of esp help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

well why are you trying to use an IIFE (immediatly invoked function expression) inside a function? You already have a scope inside esp() so there is no need for an additional IIFE.

Remove the wrapping function expression:

```js
// remove IIFE: (function(){ ... })()

    function esp() {

      let initialize = function(data) {
          let regex = /if\(!\w+\['(\w+)']\)continue/;
          let result = regex.exec(data);
          if (result) {
              const inView = result[1];
              const push = Array.prototype.push;
              Array.prototype.push = function(...args) {
                  push.apply(this, args);
                  if (args[0] instanceof Object && args[0].isPlayer) {
                      Object.defineProperty(args[0], inView, {value: true, configurable: false});
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      

      const decode = window.TextDecoder.prototype.decode;
      window.TextDecoder.prototype.decode = function(...args) {
          let data = decode.apply(this, args);
          if (data.length > 1050000) { //1050000 ideal val
              console.log(data);
              initialize(data);
          }
          return data;
      }

    }


    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (document.activeElement !== document.body) return;
    var char = event.key.toUpperCase();
    switch (char) {
            case 'Q':
            esp();
            break;
    }
    }, 750);
```

Comment: It still isnt working when i i try to call the esp function when q is pressed but i put a alert box in the function esp and it worked but not my esp it still works when i put esp(); by itself outside of a function

Comment: well, you could try console.log() and find out if everything already exists by the time the event is raised.

like:
    console.log(window); console.log(window.TextDecoder);
within your esp() function.

Comment: For me it sounds like the decode() function is already called before the keydown event is raised. So when you change it with TextDecoder.prototype.decode on keydown it has no effect, because everything already happened.
Calling esp() outside of the event handler will change the prototype immediatly before it is called